# Can a QR code be the same with different inputs?

Tags: java, android, qr-code, zxing

Can a QR code be the same with different inputs? If so, is it possible to create it using zxing? And how?

Comment: Wel, think about it: if two distinct inputs could lead to the same output, how would you ever possibly decode the output? So clearly not.

Comment: There are apps that use Dynamic QR code for mobile payments. I'm seeking to recreate this kind of apps for my school project

Comment: Sure. Why do you think identical inputs would produce the same output in such a case?

Comment: it's rather the case, that two differently looking QR may be one and the same thing.